# Timeout function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have a function, in Python (3.x), which force to the script itself to terminate, like :

```
i_time_value = 10
mytimeout(i_time_value )   # Terminate the script if not in i_time_value seconds 
for i in range(10):
   print("go")
   time.sleep(2)
```

Where "mytimeout" is the function I need : it terminate the script in "arg" seconds if the script is not terminated.

I have seen good solutions for put a timeout to a function [here](https://code.google.com/p/verse-quiz/source/browse/trunk/timeout.py) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821156/timeout-function-using-threading-in-python-does-not-work), but I don't want a timeout for a function but for the script.

Also :

- I know that I can put my script in a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827874/timeout-a-python-function-in-windows?rq=1) or using something like subprocess and use it with a
  timeout, I tried it and it works, but I want something more simple.
- It must be Unix & Windows compatible.
- The function must be universal i.e. : it may be add to any script in
  one line (except import)
- I need a function not a 'how to put a timeout in a script'.

Comment: What does `mytimeout` do?

Comment: "mytimeout" is the function I need : it terminate the script in "arg" seconds if the script is not terminated. I edit my question.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What does not work with your code?

Comment: My code is an example of what I want, I don't have "mytimeout" function working.

Comment: Would you be executing the script from python using something like subprocess?

Comment: @Harman Sure I could, but it is more or less the same solution as putting it in a function : it works, but having a function to do it would be more simple (even if the function is not simple to write). I edit my post to be more clear.

Comment: How about killing it with a signal ?

Comment: @Harman signal is not Windows compatible.

Comment: Which python version are you using ? A few are available 2.7 onwards

Comment: @Harman Clear in the question : 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> signal is not Windows compatible.

You can send *some* signals on Windows e.g.:

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT) # send Ctrl+C to itself
```

You could use `threading.Timer` to call a function at a later time:

```
from threading import Timer

def kill_yourself(delay):
    t = Timer(delay, kill_yourself_now)
    t.daemon = True # no need to kill yourself if we're already dead
    t.start()
```

where `kill_yourself_now()`:

```
import os
import signal
import sys

def kill_yourself_now():
    sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT if sys.platform == 'win32' else signal.SIGINT
    os.kill(os.getpid(), sig) # raise KeyboardInterrupt in the main thread
```

If your scripts starts other processes then see: [how to kill child process(es) when parent dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23434842/4279) See also, [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279) -- it demonstrates how to kill a process tree.

Comment: Reported for promoting suicide.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this.

```
import sys
import time
import threading

def set_timeout(event):
    event.set()

event = threading.Event()
i_time_value = 2

t = threading.Timer(i_time_value, set_timeout, [event])
t.start()

for i in range(10):

    print("go")

    if event.is_set():
        print('Timed Out!')
        sys.exit()

    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Clearly not a good answer for me : you didn't make an universal function, you  put an event in a loop in the main script.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of googling turned [this answer](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577028-timeout-any-function/) up:

```
import multiprocessing as MP
from sys import exc_info
from time import clock

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 60

################################################################################

def timeout(limit=None):
    if limit is None:
        limit = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
    if limit <= 0:
        raise ValueError()
    def wrapper(function):
        return _Timeout(function, limit)
    return wrapper

class TimeoutError(Exception): pass

################################################################################

def _target(queue, function, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        queue.put((True, function(*args, **kwargs)))
    except:
        queue.put((False, exc_info()[1]))

class _Timeout:

    def __init__(self, function, limit):
        self.__limit = limit
        self.__function = function
        self.__timeout = clock()
        self.__process = MP.Process()
        self.__queue = MP.Queue()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cancel()
        self.__queue = MP.Queue(1)
        args = (self.__queue, self.__function) + args
        self.__process = MP.Process(target=_target, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        self.__process.daemon = True
        self.__process.start()
        self.__timeout = self.__limit + clock()

    def cancel(self):
        if self.__process.is_alive():
            self.__process.terminate()

    @property
    def ready(self):
        if self.__queue.full():
            return True
        elif not self.__queue.empty():
            return True
        elif self.__timeout < clock():
            self.cancel()
        else:
            return False

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.ready is True:
            flag, load = self.__queue.get()
            if flag:
                return load
            raise load
        raise TimeoutError()

    def __get_limit(self):
        return self.__limit

    def __set_limit(self, value):
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError()
        self.__limit = value

    limit = property(__get_limit, __set_limit)
```

It might be Python 2.x, but it shouldn't be terribly hard to convert.