# Why pytest quit once an unit test(@pytest.mark.timeout(3)) timeout?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I install `pytest` and `pytest-timeout`, I follow the instrunction of `pytest-timeout` in https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeout/ to set timeout for each unit test.

And I want to only fail the unit test if it run out of time, and continue to run the other unit tests.

Please see my unit tests code:

```
# content of test_log.py
import time
import pytest

class TestDemo(object):
    @pytest.mark.timeout(60)
    def test_01(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        assert "1"

    @pytest.mark.timeout(3)
    def test_02(self):
        time.sleep(4)
        assert "1"

    @pytest.mark.timeout(3)
    def test_03(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        assert "1"
```

Now the problem is, I run this code in my Windows 7, the test will stop once the second time run out of time, the 3rd unit test is not run.

I have the log like following:

D:\dev\pytestlog>pytest

================== test session starts ==============

platform win32 -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.8.2, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: D:\dev\pytestlog, inifile:
plugins: timeout-1.3.2, instafail-0.4.0
collected 3 items

test_log.py .

++++++++++++++++++++++++ Timeout ++++++++++++++++++++++++

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Stack of MainThread (17636) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

File "c:\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

... (too many logs here)

File "D:\dev\pytestlog\test_log.py", line 15, in test_02
    time.sleep(4)

++++++++++++++++++++++++ Timeout ++++++++++++++++++++++++

D:\dev\pytestlog>

Comment: I'm wondering how a unit test can time out? Did you mock your dependencies properly?

Comment: Hi Klaus, you can see https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeout/, use `@pytest.mark.timeout` can mark individual tests as having a timeout

Comment: What I mean: a unittest should not take a long time, if it waits for something then it is not proper unittest because it has dependencies.

Comment: Yes Klaus you are right in some cases, pytest is a unittest framwork and it also can do something more, in my porject some tests need access certain device, by default the test will try again and again(up to 5 minutes) if the device is not accessable, I want to fail these tests in reasonable time(like 30 sec), to make the whole test excution short.

Comment: @KlausD. Pytest was originally a unit test framework but it can used for 'higher level tests" like functional tests. See for example this blog post: https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/testing-a-flask-application-using-pytest/ (so timeout makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative you can use a timeout decorator as indicates these link:

[timeout decorator in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48980413/3782128)

The test code should look like this:

```
# content of test_log.py
import time
from timeout import timeout

class TestDemo(object):
    @timeout(60)
    def test_01(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        assert "1"

    @timeout(3)
    def test_02(self):
        time.sleep(4)
        assert "1"

    @timeout(3)
    def test_03(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        assert "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

> the 3rd unit test is not run. exit on first error

To exit on first error for pytest

```
-x, --exitfirst       exit instantly on first error or failed test.
pytest -v --exitfirst test_log.py
```

with nose2

-F, --fail-fast       Stop the test run after the first error or failure

```
nose2 -F
```

with nosetests

```
 -x, --stop            Stop running tests after the first error or failure
```

> To run all tests, regardless of errors

```
pytest -v --continue-on-collection-errors test_log.py 

--continue-on-collection-errors
                    Force test execution even if collection errors occur.
```

check your pytest config, the default is exit on first error